# ordering wordpress post_meta - lowest to highest

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I am currently looping through all posts and displaying a post_meta value like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
$theid = get_the_id();
$getLowestPrice = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE meta_value = '$theid'");
foreach ( $getLowestPrice as $post ){

get_post_meta( $post->post_id, '_wholesale_price', false );

}
```

Is there a way to order the results, lowest -> highest? At the moment they are getting displayed randomly, or as they were entered.

Comment: You can use wp query for this like as follows
`$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price','order' => 'ASC' ) );`

Comment: i have tried, this and just get a continuous loop?

Comment: just put `'meta_key' => '_wholesale_price'` in above query insteat of `'meta_key' => 'price'`

Comment: thats what i did, but it just keeps looping through

Comment: can you show me your whole page code?

Comment: i have added the complete query above

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
<?php 
 global $wpdb;
 $table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
 $theid = get_the_id();
 $getLowestPrice = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE meta_value = '$theid'");
$all_post = array();
foreach ( $getLowestPrice as $post ){
   $all_post[] = $post->post_id; 

}
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $all_post, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => '_wholesale_price','order' => 'ASC') );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<div>' . get_post_meta( $get_the_ID(), '_wholesale_price', false );() . '</div>';
}
 } else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit wrong to me. If you're trying to order posts by the value of a meta key (unless I'm mistaken, that is what you're doing) then I would normally go about it using [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
global $wp_query;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => '[YOUR POST TYPE]', 
  'meta_key' => '_wholesale_price', 
  'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num', // meta_value_num for value
  'order' => 'ASC' // or DSC for low/high
);

$wp_query - new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    $wp_query->the_post(); 

    // Your loop

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, i have tried the above. Obviously changing the post-type and and content into the loop. But i get an error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object

Comment: iv managed to soove that by adding global $wp_query; but no i get an infinite loop!?

Comment: Ah sorry about that - forgot to mention global query var. I've added this now. Can you paste the code inside your loop?